# File protocal URL embaded as hyperlink is giving 'Not allowed to load local resource:' error

Tags: html, hyperlink, filesystems, fileserver

Clicking on the below link gives the error 'Not allowed to load local resource:' whereas, the same link pasted to the new tab is fetching the file.

```
<a href=\"file://filesrvp.servizi.bbmp/root/Applicazioni/Service%20Desk/CONFIGURAZIONE%20jamadagni%20A32-S20_Manuale%20Ver.%203.2.pdf\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\" target=\"_blank\">
```

What should I do to make it work as a hyperlink?